# How to convert Time into decimal float in Google Sheets using Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I want to convert the time `HH:MM` into `H.xx`

Like I am getting it in this format: `Sat Dec 30 00:00:00 GMT+05:21 1899`

But this value is `04:29` in cell. I want it to be `4.5` hours to multiply it to hourly rate.

Comment: I found an answer on [superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/1036327/how-to-convert-a-duration-into-a-number-of-hours-in-google-spreadsheets) maybe this will help if you still need help.

Comment: There are other ways for similar approaches ([stackoverflow.com/a/72821500/2371987](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72821500/2371987)). Please be free to try other ways. For my side, it went well.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

### Google Sheets

In Google Sheets, if you have a date/time value in a cell (e.g. "D9"), then use `=HOUR(D9)+(MINUTE(D9)/60)`.

If the value is stored in the format `04:29`, then use `=INDEX(SPLIT(D9, ":"), 1) + (INDEX(SPLIT(D9, ":"), 2)/60)`.

---

### Google Sheets API & Google Apps Script

If you want to use the Google Sheets API or Google Apps Script, then you can use javascript.

You need to use the [getMinutes()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getminutes.asp) method and divide by 60, then add that to the hour (using [getHours()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gethours.asp)).

```
var date = new Date();
var minutes = date.getMinutes();
var output = date.getHours() + (minutes/60);
```

Be aware that this is ignoring seconds.

If the value in the cell is stored as a string like `04:29`, then you'll need to [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) it.

```
var time = "04:29";
var hour = Number(time.split(":")[0]);
var minutes = Number(time.split(":")[1]);
var output = hour + (minutes/60);
```

Comment: Split method doesn't work in google sheets. Had already tried this.

Comment: @TheOnlyAnil Sorry, I was stuck in the Google Apps Script mentality. I've revised my answer.

Comment: @TheOnlyAnil Can you please provide a screenshot of your input (the value) and your script/formula?

Comment: Thanks I just had to create another column for this and it works quite fine.

Answer (score 23):

Just Multiply your Duration by 24.

Example:

```
Time In     | Time out   | Duration | Decimal
11:45:00 AM | 3:40:00 PM | 3:55:00  | 3.92
```

You also have to alter the format of the cell containing the decimal from Automatic to Number in order for this to work in Google Sheets.

Comment: Simple and accurate. Thx

Answer (score 5):

All you need is TO_PURE_NUMBER()
https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094243?hl=en

Example:

```
// The following
A1=DATEVALUE("2020-05-18 06:09:18.821 ")+TIMEVALUE("2020-05-18 06:09:18.821 ")
A2=TO_PURE_NUMBER(A1)
A3=TO_DATE(A2)

// Results in the following, first result is just a formatted date
2020-05-18 6:09:19
43969.25647
5/18/2020
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried the above methods with limited success, as I needed to have another cell to convert the time value to after calculation. However, I tried out a modification of this, and to my surprise, it works. I'll share my solution and hope it helps.

I have a Start Time and an End Time. Let's say my Start Time is in `D6` and my End Time is in `E6`.

With the above formulas, I would have to have a cell (let's say `F6`) which does `E6-D6`, then another cell (let's say `G6`) to convert `F6` from time to decimals.

I short-cut this by using:

`=INDEX(SPLIT(E6-D6, ":"), 1) + (INDEX(SPLIT(E6-D6, ":"), 2)/60)`

directly into `F6` without the need for a `G6` cell to convert.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

```
=(INDEX(SPLIT(E17, ":"), 1) &"."& (INDEX(SPLIT(E17, ":"), 2))) * hourlyRate
```

Comment: Avoid code only answers. Provide a little explanation

Answer (score 2):

This seemed to work: 
`=TEXT(D2-C2,"h:mm")*24`

Where `D2` is End Time and `C2` is Start Time,

The `=TEXT(D2-C2,"h:mm")` part both subtracts the times and converts the result into time format. The `* 24` part makes it into a usable decimal instead of time format. So, in my case, I had Start Time as `12:30 pm` and End Time as `1:20 pm`. The Sheets was seeing the difference as `:50`, which it was interpreting as 12:50am. But when you multiply by 24, it then works out, giving you .833333333.

I tested it with Start Time 10am and End Time 12pm and got 2.000000000 which is also correct.

Oops I see now you wanted it using script. Sorry. This is for within sheets.

Answer (score 0):

First of all - this thread is sure useful. It took me a couple of answers to understand what am I supposed to do, So.. I'm sharing my experience + images.. yay

What you should do:

- Select *format* --> *number* --> *automatic* (see image below)
- Insert your hours values (each value in a different cell)
- Subtract time values to represent the difference between them (in time format)
- Use `timevalue` function to represent the the difference as a decimal number
- Multiply the value with `24` in order to get the decimal representation in hours

Here's an image that displays the values I've got

[image]

And here's the formulas (assuming that time values are in columns `A` and `B`)

```
Column C  -->  B - A           for C1 formula is B1-A1, C2 formula is B2-A2 etc.
Column D  -->  timevalue(C)    for D1 formula is timevalue(C1), D2 formula is timevalue(C2) etc.
Column E  -->  D * 24          for E1 formula is D1 * 24, E2 formula is D2 * 24 etc.
```

or if you prefer this as a single formula

```
timevalue(B - A) * 24
```

Hope that I've clarified myself enough and that your are going to solve this even if you are not a software developer. Cheers

---

[image]